# Python regex to match string excluding a specific character

Tags: python, regex

If I wanted to match words ending with *at* and I use *.{1,2}* to specify that there can be 1 or 2 characters before *at*, how can I exclude the whitespace character?

This code

```
atRegex = re.compile(r'.{1,2}at')
atRegex.findall('The cat in the hat sat on the flat mat.)
```

will return

```
[' cat', ' hat', ' sat', 'flat', ' mat']
```

Can I somehow incorporate my own class that excludes the space character (for example [^ ] ) into the code?

Comment: You already have it, `[^ ]{1,2}at` or `\S{1,2}at`